# LINQ statement with conditional selection from table

Tags: linq

I am new to linq so I apologize in advance if it a dumb question. I inherited the following query and it is not producing correct results in order to fix it I have to understand what it is doing.
Here is the query, if someone can explain it to me what it is doing (also possibly fix it) that will be greatly appreciated.

```
**using (var dbCtx = new TLMDbContext())
  {
    var dvps = dbCtx.tblDVPTests.Where(x => x.DVPID == 2176);
// these 2 following if conditions doesnt bring correct result sets
    if (dvpMasterPhaseId.HasValue)
    {
       dvps = dvps.Where(x => x.tblDVPPhases.All(p => p.DVPMasterPhaseID ==255));
    }
    if (dvpMasterVariantId.HasValue)
    {
       dvps = dvps.Where(x => x.tblDVPPhases.All(p => p.tblDVPVariants.All(v=>v.DVPMasterVariantID==681)));
    }
}**
```

**UPDATE**
I want this following query to be written in LINQ and if one of you guys tell me what was wrong with the LINQ query above that will be great.

select * from tblDVPTest 
inner join tblDVPPhase on tblDVPTest.DVPTestID=tblDVPPhase.DVPTestID
where  dvpid=2176 and tblDVPPhase.DVPMasterPhaseID=255
Here is with both condition

select * from tblDVPTest 
inner join tblDVPPhase on tblDVPTest.DVPTestID=tblDVPPhase.DVPTestID
inner join tblDVPVariant on tblDVPPhase.DVPPhaseID=tblDVPVariant.DVPPhaseID
where  dvpid=2176 and tblDVPPhase.DVPMasterPhaseID=255 and tblDVPVariant.DVPMasterVariantID=681

Comment: We definitely need more information than this to help. You say that the conditions don't bring correct results. What are you expecting? What is actually happening?

Comment: if you guys can help me understand what is happening that will be great. Idea is this for the first filter

Comment: i reposted this in the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301930/linq-delima-to-convert-sql-into-linq

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from code, you are using entity framework to interact with database. Below is a high level explanation:

1. Create DbContext object.
2. Select everything from table `tblDVPTests` into variable `dvps` where column `DVPID` of table `tblDVPTests` matches value of variable `dvpNum`.
3. If nullable variable `dvpMasterPhaseId` is not null then select only those values from `dvps` where referenced table `tblDVPPhases` has all rows with column `DVPMasterPhaseID` value matching with variable `dvpMasterPhaseId` value.  Store result in `dvps`. If variable `dvpMasterPhaseId` is null skip this step.
4. If nullable variable `dvpMasterVariantId` is not null then select only those values from `dvps` where referenced table `tblDVPPhases` has all rows with column `DVPMasterVariantID` value matching with variable `dvpMasterVariantId` value. Store result in `dvps`. If variable `dvpMasterVariantId` is null skip this step.
5. Dispose DbCOntext object.

Note: There is a foreign key relationship between table `tblDVPTests` and `tblDVPPhases`.

To fix your issue first of all you should let us know what exactly you are expecting in the result.

Comment: Thank you. Let me see what is it the I am expecting in the result and then i will ask how I can achieve that.