# LINQ delima to convert sql into LINQ

Tags: linq

I am new to linq so I apologize in advance if it a dumb question. I inherited the following query and it is not producing correct results in order to fix it I have to understand what it is doing.
Here is the query.

```
  using (var dbCtx = new TLMDbContext())
  {
    var dvps = dbCtx.tblDVPTests.Where(x => x.DVPID == 2176);
// these 2 following if conditions doesnt bring correct result sets
    if (dvpMasterPhaseId.HasValue)
    {
       dvps = dvps.Where(x => x.tblDVPPhases.All(p => p.DVPMasterPhaseID ==255));
    }
    if (dvpMasterVariantId.HasValue)
    {
       dvps = dvps.Where(x => x.tblDVPPhases.All(p => p.tblDVPVariants.All(v=>v.DVPMasterVariantID==681)));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I want this following query to be written in LINQ and if one of you guys tell me what was wrong with the LINQ query above that will be great.

Following expression

dvps = dvps.Where(x => x.tblDVPPhases.All(p => p.DVPMasterPhaseID ==255));

**Should be equivalent to this SQL Query.**

```
select * from tblDVPTest 
inner join tblDVPPhase on tblDVPTest.DVPTestID=tblDVPPhase.DVPTestID
where  dvpid=2176 and tblDVPPhase.DVPMasterPhaseID=255
```

Here is with both condition
** LINQ**

dvps = dvps.Where(x => x.tblDVPPhases.All(p => p.tblDVPVariants.All(v=>v.DVPMasterVariantID==681)));

**Should be equivalent to this SQL Query.**

```
select * from tblDVPTest 
inner join tblDVPPhase on tblDVPTest.DVPTestID=tblDVPPhase.DVPTestID
inner join tblDVPVariant on tblDVPPhase.DVPPhaseID=tblDVPVariant.DVPPhaseID
where  dvpid=2176 and tblDVPPhase.DVPMasterPhaseID=255 and tblDVPVariant.DVPMasterVariantID=681
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are you getting some result you're not expecting? If so, please provide us with your results. What's happening that makes you think that something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code is adding two conditional filters (where) to the original query. Each extra filter limits the items included in the result.

In case the variable dvpMasterPhaseId is non-null the query only includes the items for which All related DPVPhases have a dvpMasterVariantId of 255

If the variable dvpMasterVariantId is non-null the query only includes the items for which All the related Variants of All the related Phases have a DVPMasterVariantID of 681.

The SQL code will not just show the DPV Tests for which ALL Phases / Variants meet these conditions, but where ANY of the Phases / Variants meet these conditions. Moreover it will return a separate row for each Test / Phase / Variant that meets these conditions